# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'balance' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
import random
import time

def set_balance():

    print("Welcome to balance manager")
    print()
    print("1, Demo mode (10,000 play chips)")
    print("2, Real mode (PayPal, BTC deposit)")
    print()
    choice = int(input("Please enter your selection: "))

    if choice == 1:
        global balance 
        balance = 10000
        demomode = 1

    elif choice == 2:
        global balance

        balance = int(input("\nEnter the ammount to pay in £"))

def spin_wheel():

    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nLETS PLAY ROULETTE, YOUR BANK IS, £", balance)
    print()
    print("Red, 1")
    print("Black, 2")
    print("Please select your colour from the menu below")

    choice = int(input("\nOption selected "))
```

what have i done wrong here ?

Comment: I suggest you refactor your code to eliminate the need for a global variable, or at least the `global` keyword.

Comment: @JustinEthier, well technically the functions are global variables :)

Comment: @gnibbler - Did you just well-actually me? - http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html

Comment: @JustinEthier, did you just call me a dick?

Answer (score 2):

You should also try to define `balance` outside of your method scopes, below your import statements.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's some code missing, but you don't need to make `balance` (or `demomode`) global in set_balance.

call it like this

```
balance, demomode = set_balance()
```

You can still use the same name balance as a local variable of `set_balance` if you wish, and just return it

```
def set_balance():

    print("Welcome to balance manager")
    print()
    print("1, Demo mode (10,000 play chips)")
    print("2, Real mode (PayPal, BTC deposit)")
    print()
    choice = int(input("Please enter your selection: "))

    if choice == 1:
        balance = 10000
        demomode = True

    elif choice == 2:

        balance = int(input("\nEnter the ammount to pay in £"))
        demomode = False

    return balance, demomode
```